# How do I specify multiple hosts in OpenAPI (Swagger)?

Tags: swagger, openapi, swagger-2.0

Right now my OpenAPI 2.0 YAML file has only one host URL:

```
host: petstore.test.com
basePath: /
```

Can I use multiple hosts like this?

```
host1: petstore.test.com
host2: petstore1.test.com
host3: petstore2.dev.com
```

Comment: YAML has no concept of hosts

Answer (score 29):

OpenAPI 2.0 (Swagger 2.0) only supports a single host with multiple schemes (HTTP/HTTPS/etc.), so you can effectively have two hosts that only vary in the scheme:

```yaml
host: petstore.test.com
schemes:
  - http
  - https
```

But OpenAPI 3.x supports [multiple hosts](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/api-host-and-base-path/) with different schemes and base paths:

```yaml
servers:
  - url: https://petstore.prd.com
    description: Production server

  - url: {scheme}://petstore.dev.com/subpath
    description: Development server
    templates:
      scheme:
        enum:
          - http
          - https
        default: https
```

For more examples, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50546904/113116).

Answer (score 2):

It is now possible in [OpenApi 3.0](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/api-host-and-base-path/)

Here is a description:

> Multiple hosts are supported in OpenAPI 3.0. 2.0 supports only one
>   host per API specification (or two if you count HTTP and HTTPS as
>   different hosts). A possible way to target multiple hosts is to omit
>   the host and schema from your specification and serve it from each
>   host. In this case, each copy of the specification will target the
>   corresponding host.