# What is the significance of servers property in OpenAPI 3.0?

Tags: openapi

In the [OpenAPI 3.0 Specification](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.1.md), the root [OpenAPI Object](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.1.md#openapi-object) has the `servers` property which is an array of [Server Objects](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.1.md#serverObject). And the [Path Item Object](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.1.md#pathItemObject) also allows an optional `servers` property.

The description given in the Specification does not give a clear idea of how `servers` can be helpful.

What is the significance of the `servers` property? Do we have any example which explains the use cases of `servers` both as a direct property of the root OpenAPI object and also as a property of a path item?

Comment: Related: [Override “host” and “basePath” at the “/{path}” level](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37157721/113116), [How do I specify multiple hosts?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40583604/113116), [Schemes HTTP and HTTPS with different ports](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48303541/113116)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`servers` specifies one or more target servers for the API, in other words, the base URL for API calls. The endpoint paths (e.g. `/users/{id}`) are defined relative to these servers. Some APIs have a single target server; others may offer several servers, e.g. sandbox vs. production, or regional servers for different geographical areas (example: AWS).

By default, all operations in an OpenAPI definition use the globally defined `servers`, but `servers` may also be overridden for specific paths and operations. This is useful for APIs where some operations use a different server than the rest of the operations. This way you can document all operations in a single API definition instead of splitting it into multiple definitions, one per server.

**Example:** [Dropbox API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation)

- Most endpoints are on the `api.dropboxapi.com` domain.
- Content upload/download endpoints are on `content.dropboxapi.com`.
- Longpoll endpoint is on `notify.dropboxapi.com`.
- OAuth endpoints are on `www.dropbox.com`.

The Dropbox API definition might look like this:

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  title: Dropbox API
  version: 1.0.0

servers:
  - url: 'https://api.dropboxapi.com/2'

paths:
  # These endpoints are on api.dropboxapi.com (use global `servers`)
  /file_requests/list:
    ...
  /users/get_account:
    ...

  /files/upload:
    # File upload/download uses another target server
    servers:
      - url: 'https://content.dropboxapi.com/2'
    ...

  /files/list_folder/longpoll:
    # Longpolling uses another target server
    servers:
      - url: 'https://notify.dropboxapi.com/2'
    ...
```

Check out the [API Host and Base Path](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/api-host-and-base-path/) guide for more details and examples.