# Can I use variables in OpenAPI securitySchema?

Tags: oauth, swagger, openapi

This is what I want to do:

```json
  "components": {
    "securitySchemes": {
      "azure_auth": {
        "type": "oauth2",
        "description": "Azure Active Directory OAuth2 Flow.",
        "flows": {
          "clientCredentials": {
            "tokenUrl": "https://login.windows.net/{tenant}/oauth2/token",
            "scopes": {}
          }
        },
        "variables": {
            "tenant":"tenantId"
         }
      }
    }
  },
```

I understand that there is no place for `variables` in the securitySchemes but was wondering if anyone knew a similar solution. If not, I was considering editing the `servers` property in my spec, something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50546573/what-is-the-significance-of-servers-property-in-openapi-3-0)

Answer (score 0):

Darn, unfortunately this looks like an issue that is posted on the [OpenAPI github repo](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/551).