# Swagger UI: dropdown version select

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

I see a lot of images like this with version switch in dropdown. Apparently this thing should show only the routes of requested version (we can only see V1 routes on the screenshot but if we switch to V2 in dropdown - we'll see routes only for V2).

[image]

Is this "Select a definition" feature part of OpenAPI specification or some tweaked Swagger UI implementations? How could i do something like this in Swagger Editor? I can't find docs or examples in yaml about it.

Comment: Does this answer your question - [Swagger UI with multiple URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44819386/113116)?

Comment: Well i see people do it here and there but it's never a yaml (answer from your link looks like JavaScript) so i don't understand how to implement this in Swagger Editor. That's the main reason i asked a question.

Comment: I want to make a feature request to one of libs for swagger generation but i don't understand what is this thing - tweaked Swagger UI or part of the standard

Comment: It's a Swagger UI feature/option. OpenAPI Specification has a similar (but not quite the same) concept where you can define [multiple API servers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40599463/113116) within the same API definition.

Comment: @DenisNovac hey did you ever figure this out? I'm also wondering the same thing on how this dropdown appears consistently in Swagger UIs built from different languages?

Comment: @takanuva15 nope, but check out the question from the first comment, it might help

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can add endpoints. in rswag_ui.rb

```
Rswag::Ui.configure do |c|
  c.swagger_endpoint '/api-docs/v1/swagger.yaml', 'API V1 Docs'
  c.swagger_endpoint '/api-docs/v2/swagger.yaml', 'API v2 Docs'
end
```

This is how you can specify which specs is for which API. By adding **openapi_spec: 'v2/swagger.yaml**' or **swagger_root: 'v2/swagger.yaml** if your variable name swagger_root in swagger_helper.rb.

```
RSpec.describe "Api::lcm::Assessments", openapi_spec: 'lcm/swagger.yaml', type: :request do
// your code
end
```

**NOTE:** If you're using rspec-api to expose Swagger files (under swagger_root) as **JSON or YAML** endpoints,
then the list above should correspond to the relative paths for those endpoints